# Read access to role is not working

Tags: sitecore-client, role-management

I have created new Sitecore item in start menu and created new role to give access to item for one of our user. But item is not displaying at all in start menu when I login as that user(after new role allocated). If I allocate permission by user wise then I can able to see the item in start menu. But I need to achieve this through role, so I could use the same for multiple users.

User already have allocated with multiple roles.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you given the user any other roles at all or just the new roles?

In order to give the user basic access to Sitecore you will usually need to give them the **Sitecore Client Authoring** & **Sitecore Client Users** roles too.

There is more info on OOTB roles and what they do here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles

Also I'd recommend using the Access Viewer to check the access of your role once you have set it up:

[image]

There is more info on how to use this here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/view_the_access_rights_of_a_security_account

Also bear in mind inheritance and how this it is automatically applied to child items, from the link below:

> By default, an item inherits the access rights that are assigned to
>   the items that are higher up the content tree (the ancestors). For
>   example, a security administrator can configure the security settings
>   of a single item and all the items that are lower down the content
>   tree (the descendants) automatically inherit the same settings.
>   However, if there is an item that should not inherit any security
>   settings from its ancestors, you can use the Inheritance access right
>   to deny the item the right to inherit the security settings.

Depending on what permissions are being inherited you may need to break inheritance to your item to get permissions to work as you want.

More info here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/the_inheritance_access_right

Comment: Yes lots other role also allocated to same user.

Comment: Try using the access viewer as I've mentioned above to see what access your user has with this role. You might find other roles are cancelling out permissions on your custom role.

Comment: I've also updated my answer to include info on inheritance. I'd suggest starting small, perhaps create a new 'test' user and add your new roles and and add one other required role at a time and testing as you go to see what role is breaking access.

Comment: Take a look also in this article https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/assigning_access_rights which will show you how rules are applied for permissions. This could be causing trouble!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have not set up any 'deny' permissions, just in case this causes issues with users who have multiple roles.

Instead, break the inheritance so that previous inherited security is no longer applied and then grant the correct role this access.

This is almost always a better approach then using explicit deny.